# Stop bashrc execution on condition without exiting terminal

Tags: bash, exit

I have a `.bashrc` that I want to look a bit like this:

```
testfunc() {
    if [ condition passes ] 
    then
        stop all execution
    fi
}

jobA() {
     testfunc
     ...
}

jobB() {
     testfunc
     ...
}
```

The question is how can I stop all execution without exiting the terminal? I am aware of only two options to stop execution:

1. `exit`: which causes the terminal to be closed as well
2. `return`: Which only stops execution in the function where the return lies. I could have all functions that call `testfunc` check its return code, but that's a lot of duplicated if statements.

Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the result of `testfunc` is not that cumbersome though: `testfunc || return` instead of your bare `testfunc` is all you need (you don't have to have the whole `if/then/fi`).

To your question though... no, there's AFAIK no way to exit all functions but not the shell itself.

Answer (score 1):

Just put your jobs into a sub shell using round parenthesis. Then you can exit the sub shell.

```
$ type testfunc
testfunc is a function
testfunc () 
{ 
    if true; then
        exit;
    fi
}
$ type jobA
jobA is a function
jobA () 
{ 
    testfunc
}
$ type jobB
jobB is a function
jobB () 
{ 
    testfunc
}
$ ( jobA; jobB; )
$
```

And the terminal will not exit.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap the whole `.bashrc` code inside a single serving `while` loop, you can use `break` to leave it:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                     

# for testing
condition="true"

# a test func                                                                      
func() {
    if [ $condition == "true" ]
    then
        # 1 to break after calling, 0 not
        return 1
    fi
}
# the while    
while [ $((++i)) -eq 1 ]
# the main .bashrc code goes here
do
    # "exit" after a function
    func || break

    # or exit from main
    if [ $condition != "true" ]
    then
        break
    fi
done
# anything after the above done gets executed after break
```